# Keras - How to share the convolutional part of a CNN with 2 separate FullyConnected layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a CNN aiming at predicting 2 different volumes (systolic, and diastolic) from a set of cardiac MRI images.

First thing I have done is implementing 2 separate "sequential" CNN, each of them predicting one volume.

First defining the model :

```
def get_model():
    dim_img = 64
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Activation(activation=center_normalize, input_shape=(30, dim_img, dim_img)))

    # CONVOLUTIONAL LAYERS
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3,border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    # FULLY CONNECTED LAYERS
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, W_regularizer=l2(1e-3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=root_mean_squared_error)
    return model
```

And then, I call two different model to predict 2 different volumes :

```
model_systole= get_model()
model_diastole= get_model()
print('Fitting systole model...')
hist_systole = model_systole.fit_generator(generator_train_sys, nb_epoch = 1,samples_per_epoch=N_train,validation_data=generator_validate_sys,nb_val_samples=N_validate)

print('Fitting Diastole model...')
hist_diastole = model_diastole.fit_generator(generator_train_dia,nb_epoch = 1,samples_per_epoch=N_train,validation_data=generator_validate_dia, nb_val_samples=N_validate)
```

However, I thus have to train two different models, with 2 convolutional parts.

===> I would like to **share the convolutional part** of my networks,  and add to it 2 different FC layers to predict both my volumes (1 unique convolutional part and two separate FC layers sharing the convolutional part)

Would you know how to do this with Keras ? Do I have to switch to Keras Graph mode ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `get_model()` twice, it creates two different instances. That means they will be initialized with two different initial set of weights. Also, they are different models, so they are in no way related during back-propagation.

You will have to switch to the `Model` class. I will strongly suggest you to update Keras so that you get the `Model` class instead of `Graph`.

```
input1 = Input(30 ,64, 64)
input2 = Input(30 ,64, 64)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu') # shared

model1 = conv1(input1)
model2 = conv1(input2)
model1 = Flatten()(model1)
model2 = Flatten()(model2)

# following dense layers do not share the weight
model1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3))(model1)
model2 = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3))(model2)
model1 = Dense(1)(model1)
model2 = Dense(1)(model2)

model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[model1, model2])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Basically, layers are now callable. So I first created one convolutional layer and called it with two different inputs, so its weights are shared. However, I called a two dense layers by instantiating them twice (like `Dense(512)`), so  they are not shared.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I'll try this this evening.

Comment: Ok. You will have to spend some time learning the new `Model` class but it is worth it. Please mark the answer as accepted if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Why do we need to flatten the model?

Comment: @aditya Because the output of `conv1` needs to work with a `Dense` layer. Now, `Dense` layer performs nothing but `f(w^T * x)` where `f` is the activation, `w` is the weight matrix and `x` is the output of `conv1`. However, without flattening, output of `conv1` is a 3D tensor for each sample in a batch, so we flatten it, otherwise matrix dimensions will not match for the multiplication of `w^T * x`. Dense layers do not take into account spatial relationships into account for this reason. Also, including dense layers will not allow you to change the size of the input.